# squid and https URLs

Tags: proxy, https, squid

I have installed `squid` as a non-transparent proxy/cache server with `--enable-ssl` configuration. It is a child of a parent proxy server `proxy1.ut.ac.ir`.

Everything is OK for `HTTP` URLs, but any `HTTPS` URL is responded by a `404 Server not found` (for example for [Gmail](http://www.gmail.com) or https://www.google.com).

This is the `access.log` entries for opening [www.gmail.com](http://www.gmail.com):

```
1279493581.278    544 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/302 1136 GET http://mail.google.com/mail/ - DEFAULT_PARENT/proxy1.iut.ac.ir text/html
1279493581.283      0 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/404 0 CONNECT www.google.com:443 - DIRECT/- -
```

And squid in terminal says:

```
2010/07/18 18:52:27| ipcacheParse: No Address records in response to 'www.google.com'
```

---

Here is the `squid.conf`:

```
http_port 3128

http_access allow all

cache_peer proxy1.ut.ac.ir parent 3128 0 no-query default no-digest no-netdb-exchange

cache_dir ufs /usr/local/squid/var/cache 100 16 256
coredump_dir /usr/local/squid/var/cache
```

There is no problem when i set `proxy1.ut.ac.ir` as the proxy server in browsers so there is nothing wrong in parent proxy server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the server hosting squid can't resolve the name "www.google.com", to me.

The second line in your access.log sample is telling you that squid isn't sending the request to the parent cache, but rather is attempting a direct connection to "www.google.com" (the `DIRECT/-` is the tip-off). If you want CONNECT requests to be sent to the parent cache, add the `never_direct allow CONNECT` directive to your squid.conf file and you'll be in business.

Comment: Thanks Evan! Problem solved!
But why squid tries to connect to webserver directly for `CONNECT` requests while uses parent proxy for `GET` requests.

Is it a default behavior or i am missing something?

Comment: There was same problem with `POST` method and it is solved in similar way. But why squid just redirect `GET` requests to parent proxy while tries to other methods (`POST` and `CONNECT`) directly to webserver?
am I missing a configuration?

Comment: I wasn't aware of the default for POST, but the behavior you saw with CONNECT was because of a default.